# Angular validation firing immediately on form initialization

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form control `nameFormControl` with some validators and an `updateOn` property:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      nameFormControl: ["john", {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]
        , updateOn: "blur"
      }]
    });
  }
```

I want to fire the validators on blur event only. But when the form loads for the first time, validators are firing immediately and setting both `nameFormControl` and `myFormGroup`'s invalid property to `true` because `nameFormControl`'s initial value length is 4. How can I skip firing the validators until blur operation happens?

I am using:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.4
Node: 14.17.3
Angular: 14.2.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to implement your own Validator function and using a boolean inside your component which deactivates the controls inside the Validator on the first time they are done (when Angular runs the validators at the very start).

Something like:

```
public isFirstControl:boolean = true;
```

And:

```
customValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control:AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null => {
      if(this.isFirstControl){
        this.isFirstControl = false;
        return null;
      }

      //Your actual validation logic here
      if(toto){
        return { required: true };
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Then give this validator function to your FormControl.